# Matrix multiplication sequential vs parallel performance test

Tags: java, performance, matrix, parallel-processing, performance-testing

I am doing performance tests on an algorithm I wrote for parallel matrix multiplication in Java.
I get the number of cpu cores from runtime, then divide the calculation loop between the available cores, using a thread pool. I measure the run times of the sequential and parallel version, then display the results in an excel chart.
There I noticed a strange behavior:
[image]

This is a performance test of matrix multiplication of square matrices from size 50 to size 1500. The results are an average calculated from 10 runs. The measurements are indicated by dots on the lines and the lines themselves are smoothed.
As you can see, the lines of the sequential and parallel functions cross two times. Actually, three times, but the first one is around the matrix sizes 60-80, hence not visible in this chart. That is normal, since threads introduce overhead, so fast functions run better sequentially.

Are the other two intersections normal? I have done multiple measurements in the 500-700 region, this behavior seems prevalent.

Things I think could play part in this: OS thread management, JVM thread management, some thread pool-specific behavior, Intel Hyper Threading (since I have an intel i5-3210M cpu in my machine).
However, what seems to be behaving irregularly (to me, at least) is actually the sequential algorithm. Notice how, until it hits a size of 650, it barely suffers any time penalty. Then it steepens abruptly at a size of 650.
In comparison, the parallel curve seems pretty smooth.

I have checked the algorithms a few times, I'm pretty sure they are bug-free. The results of the calculations are correct, that's for sure.
My functions are measured in a double loop: the outer one repeats the measurements for later averaging and the inner one increases the matrix size every step.
Inside that, the source matrices are randomized, the sequential function is run and measured, then the parallel one is run and measured.

Is the behavior on the chart normal?

In main:

```
    // do n measurements
    for (int n = 0; n < measurements; ++n) {
        // display progress
        System.out.println("Progress: " + (float) n / measurements * 100 + "%");
        // single measurement
        for (int i = 0, size_n = size; i < steps; ++i, size_n += increment) {

            // allocate memory for matrices: source a, source b, result
            float[][] src_a_seq = new float[size_n][size_n];
            float[][] src_b_seq = new float[size_n][size_n];
            float[][] src_a_par = new float[size_n][size_n];
            float[][] src_b_par = new float[size_n][size_n];
            float[][] res_seq = new float[size_n][size_n];
            float[][] res_par = new float[size_n][size_n];

            // fill source matrices with random values
            miscManager.genRandMatrix(src_a_seq, size_n);
            miscManager.genRandMatrix(src_b_seq, size_n);
            miscManager.genRandMatrix(src_a_par, size_n);
            miscManager.genRandMatrix(src_b_par, size_n);

            // create time variables
            long before, after, delta_t;

            // time measurement, serial multiplication
            before = System.nanoTime();
            serialMultiplier.mul(src_a_seq, src_b_seq, res_seq, size_n);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            delta_t = after - before;
            // add measurement to data
            data[i][0] += delta_t;

            // time measurement, parallel multiplication
            before = System.nanoTime();
            parallelMultiplier.mul(src_a_par, src_b_par, res_par, size_n);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            delta_t = after - before;
            // add measurement to data
            data[i][1] += delta_t;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Progress: 100.0%");
```

serial multiplication:

```
public void mul(float[][] src_a, float[][] src_b, float[][] res, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                res[i][j] += src_a[i][k] * src_b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

parallel multiplication:

```
public void mul(float[][] src_a, float[][] src_b, float[][] res, int size) {

    // calculate data required for labor division
    int n = size * size;
    int load = n / cpuCoreCount + 1;
    int remainder = n % cpuCoreCount;

    // create thread pool
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpuCoreCount);

    // assign tasks
    int m = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < remainder) {
        taskExecutor.execute(new MultiplierUnit(src_a, src_b, res, size, m, m + load));
        m += load;
        ++i;
    }
    --load;
    while (i < cpuCoreCount) {
        taskExecutor.execute(new MultiplierUnit(src_a, src_b, res, size, m, m + load));
        m += load;
        ++i;
    }

    // wait for tasks to finish
    taskExecutor.shutdown();
    try {
      taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("error: thread pool interrupted exception");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The values in the data array are later divided by "measurements" to get the average.

MultiplierUnit:

```
public class MultiplierUnit implements Runnable {

    // source a, source b, result
    private final float[][] src_a, src_b, res;
    // matrix dimensions, first entry to execute, last entry to execute
    private final int size, first, last;

    public MultiplierUnit(float[][] src_a, float[][] src_b, float[][] res,
            int size, int first, int last) {
        this.src_a = src_a;
        this.src_b = src_b;
        this.res = res;
        this.size = size;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    // parallel multiplication
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // index setup
        int i = first / size;
        int j = first % size;
        int n = first;

        // computation
        while (n < last) {
            while (j < size && n < last) {
                res[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    res[i][j] += src_a[i][k] * src_b[k][j];
                }
                ++n;
                ++j;
            }
            j = 0;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would wonder what was also happening at matrix size 650; perhaps the matrix size hitting some sort of cache limit?  A similar change in profile seems to happen at matrix size 500 for the parallel.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i have included the relevant code, pretty much all of it is relevant though

Comment: I would maybe create a [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark. Writing custom benchmarking code is notoriously unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

A couple remarks:

1. to eliminate a large fixed overhead from the parallel computation you must have the `ExecutorService` as a singleton and reuse it. This in itself may explain the behavior of the parallel-computation line in your chart;
2. writing to the same array from several threads is liable to the effects of *false sharing*, where CPU caches are overwhelmed with write collisions. This will then show up as a deformation in your chart;
3. instead of the `ExecutorService` you should consider an approach based on the Fork/Join framework, which will more efficiently split the work and, with the right approach, can eliminate false sharing (although by doing some array copying, but that can pay off).